# How to get the path of the internal Downloads directory in Android?

Tags: android

I need to get the path of the internal Downloads directory.

Things I have tried:

```
val home = System.getProperty("user.home")
val downloadsDirectory = File("$home/Downloads"

val downloadsDirectory = File("/storage/emulated/0/Download")
```

System.getProperty("user.home") just returns an empty string.

I also tried

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

and it returned this path /storage/emulated/0/Download 
but then the downloadsDirectory.listFiles() method returns null, although I have a file in the directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Android 9 and below, use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`.

On Android 10 and higher, [stop thinking in terms of files](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html). Instead, switch to the Storage Access Framework or, for [limited scenarios](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/01/11/scoped-storage-stories-diabolical-details-downloads.html), use `MediaStore.Downloads`.

Comment: Well I tried Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) too, and it returns this path "/storage/emulated/0/Download" and the downloadsDirectory.listFiles() method returns null

Comment: @DinuNicolae: Most likely, you don't have permission to work with [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). You will need to [request](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, both in the manifest and at runtime. Your book on Android app development should cover this process, if it was written in the past five years.

Comment: I am not an Android dev. I thought this is enough)
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: @DinuNicolae: That is sufficient for Android 5.1 and older. On Android 6.0 and higher, you also need to [request the permission at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting).

Comment: Thank you. I can get the path and see the file list when I try it on a real phone, but on the emulator the directory is empty. I wonder if i did something wrong or if it is the emulator.

Comment: @DinuNicolae: If the emulator is running Android 10 or higher, [you will not be able to access that directory](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html), regardless of permission.

Comment: Thank you for telling me. I was already going insane while trying to access that directory :D